# Getting permission denied error when trying to restore fabric network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

**Docker swarm**

**Hyperledger fabric v1.4.4**

I'm trying to restore the blockchain network with all the previous data. So what I did that I have created a backup of `/var/hyperledger/production/node_type` directory for every node. And then using these directory like below in `docker-compose.yaml` file

Lets assume I have created a backup of `orderer1` node in `myproject/networks/orderer1` directory then under volume section I'm doing something like `myproject/networks/orderer1/production:/var/hyperledger/production`.

**compose-file before network restoration**

```
volumes:
  - orderer1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer:rw
```

**compose file for restoring network**

```
volumes:
  /home/delta/GoWorkspace/src/github.com/testchain/bchain_network/orderer1/orderer:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer:rw
```

But when I'm trying to start the network it gives an error

**Orderer node**

> panic: Error opening leveldb: open /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/index/LOCK: permission denied

The link that I'm following for network restoration is https://medium.com/@jariarud/hyperledger-fabric-backup-and-restore-3263561e259e

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to manually map the location of the volume like below and remove `:rw`

```
volumes:
  /home/delta/GoWorkspace/src/github.com/testchain/bchain_network/orderer1/orderer:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
```

Just leave as it is docker will take care of that  like below

```
volumes:
  - orderer1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
```

Comment: got it. Actually one of the network is currently running on docker-compose so I'm thinking of moving it to swarm therefore checking if it is possible to use the previous data with docker-swarm. 
Is it possible?

Comment: I think so. Try if you face any problem feel free to post a new question

Comment: Hi Narendra, I have updated the question that I'm using CouchDB. i forgot to mention it earlier. Bu the error shows that it is trying to access leveldb.

Comment: Will you please a new question. As I have answered for an earlier version of the question and now problem statement is focused completely ?